# Can't access Front end in oscommerce

Tags: php, oscommerce

I am newbie in oscommerce. I have site which was crashed before some days and for start my site I restore database backup which is in Godaddy.

Now the problem is that I can't access my front end but I can access back end properly.
whenever I try to access front page then its displayed Blank page.

Anybody have idea why its happening?

When I turn on error reporting then I got following errors

**Warning: require(includes/languages/affiliate.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/17/10028317/html/includes/affiliate_application_top.php on line 72**

**Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'includes/languages/affiliate.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in /home/content/17/10028317/html/includes/affiliate_application_top.php on line 72**

Comment: make sure error reporting is turned on

Comment: the error is pretty self explanatory.. you are missing files :p

Comment: @Steve. I check it and all the files are available.

Answer (score 1):

As steve said your are missing a file. The missing file is affiliate.php wich should be stored in 'includes/languages/', please check to have it.

To my knowledge languages files should be kept insead in 'includes/languages/yourlanguagefolder/'

You might have either a mistake in your config.php file or in the script 'includes/affiliate_application_top.php' in this case path for language file could be wrong in require function

Comment: I think affiliate is add-on pack in oscommerce Right??
So, Do you have any Idea how can I disable this add-on in oscommerce??

Comment: yes this is definitely a contribution, i haven't used yet so i don't know how to remove it. Be aware that often it doesn't just take to remove files to delete a contribution. I think you should find the contribution itself in oscommerce page/contribution. Once you will find it you will have to follow contribution install instruction from the end to the beginning. I hope this can help you

Comment: Now I got this error : Fatal error: Call to undefined function bts_select() in /home/content/17/10028317/html/index1.php on line 263

Comment: It's a function wich is missing. It can be either not declared in functions/general.php or any other function file, or the file that is using this function doesn't require the correct file with function. I think you should look in index1.php to see if there are correct require/requires and then inspect your functions file, starting from general.php looking for the function itself. I don't know what this function is used for.

Comment: I just googled it and this function is from basic template structure contribution. It seems oscommerce site doesn't work so i cannot read entire page of contr. but from google:

The bts_select() function (in the configure_bts.php file) has been updated to support different columns per template...